# rails & markdown error: uncaught exception: Control.TextArea requires Object.Event to be loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

So, I've got bluecloth installed and I'm trying to use the [Control.TextArea](http://livepipe.net/control/textarea) javascript WYSIWYG editor.

Anyways, I followed the tutorial on the page and when I load the corresponding view, I get an error:

uncaught exception: Control.TextArea requires Object.Event to be loaded.

This comes from Control.TextArea js file.

Any ideas? Thanks